# Sort array of tuples by 2nd element then by first element in Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell, generics, tuples

I am trying to sort this array of tuples by the 2nd element but if the elements being compared are equal, I want to sort them based off the 1st element. I've done research but can only find to sort by 1st element or by 2nd element only, instead of checking both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a function that maps `(x, y)` on `(Down y, x)` so that it first on the second item in descending order, and then by the first item:

```
import Data.List(sortOn)
import Data.Ord(Down(Down))

sortTupleSndFirst = sortOn (\(x, y) -> (Down y, x))
```

Comment: You can also write `sortBy (flip (comparing snd) <> comparing fst)` if you want to use the monoid instance for reader.